# Explain why it is the case that for each $r > 0$, there is a prime $p$ with $\frac{1}{p}<r$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand what that statement means, but for some reason I can't succinctly (because it is a question worth only 1 mark) put into words why it is the case.  Could I say that: $\frac{1}{p}\rightarrow 0$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$ and so $\frac{1}{p}=0<r$?.  That feels like showing that it is the case rather than explaining it.

This question is in the context of countable sets, if that is relevant.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows from the Archemedian Principle.  Since we have a $1/n < r$ and for any $n$ there is a prime $p > n$ we know that $1/p < 1/n$ so $1/p < r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments this property follows from the Archimedean principle.

Given some $r$ by AP we know that there is an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < r$.  And by the infinitude of the primes we know that given any $n$ there is a prime $p > n$ which means $\frac{1}{p} < \frac{1}{n}$.  So by transitivity we know $\frac{1}{p} < r$ for any $r>0$.

Comment: That's a nice way of putting it.  I'll mark your answer as correct when I'm allowed to.  Thank you.